# Is there a way to extract styles generated by emotion.js into a separate .css file?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, emotion

I am doing extensions for Сhrome. And when I write in the manifest "content_security_policy": "default-src 'self';", Сhrome refuses to apply styles that are generated, and inserted by scripts. Therefore, I want to get the styles in a separate file. I collect using Webpack

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58932468/is-it-possible-to-generate-css-files-using-emotion